# Jackson JSON infinite recursion without omiting anything from the serialization

Tags: json, hibernate, serialization, jackson

I want to serialize and eventually deserialize an object to perform an export/import operation. I use Jackson library because of the extend annotation  provided. I do break the infinite recursion by using the latest tags @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference. But the problem here @JsonBackReference does omit the annotated part from the json file so I am not able to set the relationship while importing.

The relationship btwn entities can be shown:

```
public class A{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, precision = 20)
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "a_generator", sequenceName = 
         "SEQ_A", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
   "a_generator")
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "metricDefinition", 
         fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
   @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
   @NotAudited
   @JsonManagedReference
   private Set<B> bSet= new HashSet<B>();
```

}

```
public class B{

@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, precision = 20)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "b_generator", sequenceName = "seq_b", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "b_generator")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@JsonBackReference(value = "a-b")
private A a;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "ref_a_id")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@JsonBackReference(value = "a-ref")
private A refA;


@Column(name = "is_optional")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private boolean isOptional;

@Column(name = "name")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private String name;
```

When I serialize any A object, it does serialize the B's included but the referenced A and refA are omitted. So, when I import A object of course the B's are also imported but  I do want to the relationship between the objects to be set.

Is there any idea how can I break the infinite recursion without omitting the one side of the reference?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did also try to use statement below according to answers given similar questions but it did not work so I asked the question above.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "@id")
```

it does not sufficient to break the circle. You should also add below annotation to the id property of your class.

```
  @JsonProperty("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try to break the loop either at the Parent end or at the Child end by following 3 ways

- Use @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference
- Use @JsonIdentityInfo
- Use @JsonIgnore

**Use @JsonIdentityInfo**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "nodes")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "id")
public class Node {
    ...
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "relations")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "id")
public class Relation {
    ...
}
```

Refer more in detail [here](https://ashishontech.xyz/jackson-json-infinite-recursion-problem/) with the working demo at the end.